# Detect Last Redirect for UIWebView (To Remove Indicator)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm building a simple embedded browser into my app. In the browser controller I'm showing a loading indicator in `viewWillAppear:`, hiding it in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method. Now the problem is that I came to cases where the request URL gets redirected to a new URL, which sends a new request before the user really gets any results.. which means removing the loading indicator while we still have an empty screen.

> Case Example:  http://t.co/XXX 
>   ->  http://twitter.com/XXX
>   -> https://mobile.twitter.com/XXX

I need a reliable way to detect if this is the last redirection in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. I really don't care if all of the contents / media (e.g. images) of the requested page is completely loaded, which most of the answers to this question focuses on it. What I do care about is not removing the loading indicator unless there is anything that got displayed on the screen.

I've seen the trick of tracking requests in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and check if the count is zero in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, but that supposes non-serial requests, which is not the case here. As a workaround to this, someone suggested here to delay the action by ~1 second so it can still track serial requests, but I don't see it a reliable / clean way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Stupid me, I can simply show the indicator in webViewDidStartLoad: XD

Comment: Okay, that sometimes makes an annoying 'flashing' for the indicator!